# Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `ToDos`

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and I built this app. While running code, I got this warning on console: **Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of ToDos**

This is my code:

```
return (
    <div className='container' style={todoStyle}>

      <h3 className='my-3'>ToDos List</h3>

      {props.todos.length === 0 ?
        "No ToDos to display" :
        props.todos.map((todo) => {
          return (
            <>
              <ToDoItem todo={todo} key={todo.sno} onDelete={props.onDelete} /> <hr />
            </>
          )
        })

      }

    </div>
  )
```

I have added key to `ToDoItem` yet I am getting this warning.

Comment: The `key` needs to be on the outermost element, which is the fragment `<>`.  You can use `<React.Fragment key={todo.sno}>`.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is coming probably because the unique key prop should be on outermost element in the DOM tree.

```js
return (
        <div className='container' style={todoStyle}>
          <h3 className='my-3'>ToDos List</h3>
          {props.todos.length === 0 ?
            "No ToDos to display" :
            props.todos.map((todo, _i) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={`${_i}-${todo.sno}`}>
                  <ToDoItem todo={todo} onDelete={props.onDelete}/> 
                  <hr/>
                <React.Fragment/>
              );
            });
          }
        </div>
     )
```

Also I'm not sure if `todo.sno` is unique thus implement index from map function to ensure the key prop remains unique.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. In start, array is empty and I am getting no warning but when I start to add in arrays from textboxes, I get this warning. For srno I am using this code: if (todos.length === 0) {
      sno = 0;
    } else {
      sno = todos[todos.length - 1].sno + 1;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes and it worked. I removed **hr** tag from return statement and returned only **ToDoItem** and used **hr** to show horizontal line in **ToDoItem.js** file. My new code looks like this:

```
return (
    <div className='container' style={todoStyle}>

      <h3 className='my-3'>ToDos List</h3>

      {props.todos.length === 0 ?
        "No ToDos to display" :
        props.todos.map((todo) => {
          return (
            <ToDoItem todo={todo} key={todo.sno} onDelete={props.onDelete} />
          )
        })

      }

    </div>
  )
```

ToDoItem.js:

```
return (
    <>
      <div>
        {/* <h4>{todo.sno}</h4> */}
        <h4>{todo.title}</h4>
        <p>{todo.description}</p>
        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onClick={() => { onDelete(todo) }}>Delete</button>
      </div>
      <hr />
    </>

  )
```